# The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-connection

I am trying to connect to remote database
Here is my connectionString:

```
 <add name="myprojectname.DataContext.Models.FBAppContext" 
 connectionString="Server=xxx.xx.xxx.190,1433;database=myprojectname;Integrated Security=true" 
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and I am trying other connectionStrings like:

```
 <add name="myprojectname.DataContext.Models.FBAppContext" 
 connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xx.xxx.190,1433\myprojectname-SQL1;Initial Catalog=myprojectname;Integrated Security=true" 
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Port 1433 is Opened

And I get error:
An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct. 
Inner exception: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xx.xxx.190,1433;Initial Catalog=Alllarm;Integrated Security=true"
```

Comment: I guess you use the windows authentification. "ALLLARM-SQL1" is the name of your instance?

Comment: you must specify server nome or IP adress, but not both